# Serial Connection

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, java

I was trying to communicate with my arduino uno over the serial connection from the USB. Connecting to it is usually not a problem, but what buggs me is the first transaction of the data... No matter with what I do it, java code or the serial monitor which comes with the IDE, I always have the problem that usually only one Byte is being transfered or received from the Arduino. What could be the problem? Is it just a bug and I have to live with it or can this somehow be fixed?

My Arduino Code:

```
#include "RGBdriver.h"
#define CLK 10
#define DIN 11

RGBdriver driver(CLK, DIN);
byte red = 0;
byte green = 0;
byte blue = 0;

byte newRed = 0;
byte newGreen = 0;
byte newBlue = 255;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() >= 3) {
    newRed = Serial.read();
    newGreen = Serial.read();
    newBlue = Serial.read();
  }

  if ((red != newRed) || (green != newGreen) || (blue != newBlue)) {
    red = newRed;
    green = newGreen;
    blue = newBlue;

    driver.begin();
    driver.SetColor(red, green, blue);
    driver.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the Arduino to finish the bootloader timeout after opening the serial port from the PC?

Comment: Yes, I do! The Arduino is being used for controlling the lights on my LED strip. I know it booted because they turn on and after 10-15 sec, just to be safe, I try to send the data and on the first try it turns off and on in a short time and on the second try it really changes the color.

Comment: Now I have actually looked at your code your problem is immediately obvious to me. I cover it in detail here: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: Ok what I could have changed in my code is putting Seria.available() >=3, bcs I need 3 Bytes of data for updating. But it still doesnt update the color on the first try. This also happens in the serial monitor...

Comment: I updated my code. Now it works with the serial monitor, but my java program is still not working, meaning the first attempt of sending the data doesnt work... Only after trying the data one time it will work from there on.

Comment: Are you waiting the bootloader timeout time in your java program?

Comment: Well, just to be sure I always wait for like 5-7 sec until I do anything just to be sure I am not doing something that will interupt the boot time

Comment: Even after opening the serial port in your Java program? (Open port - wait 2+ seconds - send data)

Comment: Well, I do use in the program the function setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0). I am not actually typing data in it, I send it over right away with starting the program. I also close the port on the end, because else I won't be able to access it next time.

Comment: You do know, don't you, that the act of opening the serial port resets the Arduino?

Comment: Ok,I didn't know that ... So I will try to make a while code for input of data and see what will happen then. Also, when I open the port for the second time the Arduino doesn't reset... Everything works fine from then on.

Answer (score 1):

Consider giving sufficient delay to initiate the time to receive the data. The loop would otherwise terminate since the data received is less than 3